# Not call onRequestPermissionsResult from fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-permissions

In my android project, I use this code to check & request runtime permissions:

```
public class AgentsFragmentMapTab extends RootFragment implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback 
{    
     //..
     private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
            int internet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
            int loc = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            int loc2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
            if (internet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
            }
            if (loc != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
            if (loc2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "checkAndRequestPermissions_listPermissionsNeeded(" + listPermissionsNeeded.size() + ")");
            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), LOCATION_REQ_CODE);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

            if (requestCode == LOCATION_REQ_CODE) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        }
```

This code shows the permission dialog perfectly. But when I click on the **Allow** or **Deny** button, the method `onRequestPermissionsResult()` doesn't get invoked. Why isn't it getting invoked and how to achieve this?

Comment: override the onRequestPermissionsResult method in the parent activity, then push the result to this fragment.

Comment: But I need to handle click button Allow in fragment

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use dexter permissions library

Comment: `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` only sends the result to the Activity as it doesn't know about your Fragment. Why aren't you using `requestPermissions` on `Fragment` itself?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments Override `onRequestPermissionsResult` in the parent activity

Make sure to call `super.onRequestPermissionsResult` from this activity's `onRequestPermissionsResult`

it will then send to your fragments which override `onRequestPermissionsResult`

Edited :

Here is what i did

i called  `requestPermissions(StringOfPermissions,YourRequestCode);`

inside the fragment

And Here is the code i used to add the fragment inside the activity , pretty straight forward

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, BlankFragment.newInstance("",""))
            .disallowAddToBackStack()
            .commit();
```

I overridden onRequestPermissionsResult():

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

inside the activity and fragment

when i requested from the fragment it entered the activity and then it entered the fragment

Comment: Call only in activity, but not call in fragment

Comment: even after  `super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);` in the activity ?

Comment: yes. In my activity: 
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }. But not call in fragment

Comment: I've edited the answer after testing can you check it now ? @Alexei

Comment: Not help. Same result. Not call in fragment

Comment: did you change this `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), LOCATION_REQ_CODE);`
to `requestPermissions(StringOfPermissions,YourRequestCode);` ? 

as the first one actually asks android to check the permission in the activity not in the fragment that's why you send the getActivity() @Alexei

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196100/discussion-between-hossam-eldeen-onsy-and-alexei).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), LOCATION_REQ_CODE);
```

to:

```
requestPermissions(listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_CODE);
```

And also `ContextCompat` to `ActivityCompat` and `getActivity()` to `getContext()` like:

```
int loc2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, LOCATION_REQ_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do this in the parent activity.

```
...
Fragment theFragment = 
     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_name);
...         

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_REQ_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if(theFragment instanceof AgentsFragmentMapTab) 
                    ((AgentsFragmentMapTab)theFragment).passPermissionResult(true);

            } else {
                if(theFragment instanceof AgentsFragmentMapTab) 
                    ((AgentsFragmentMapTab)theFragment).passPermissionResult(false);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your fragment, add a public method like so:

```
public void passPermissionResult(boolean allowed) {
    if(allowed) {
        // ALLOW clicked
    }
    else {
        // DENY clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't necessary. Calling `requestPermissions()` in the Fragment automatically sends the result to the Fragment for you.

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks for the correction! I learned something new today.